# Table exported into PDF is showing messy data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I'm using this plugin to export table where's rows populated by jquery and php into PDF:  ***https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin***

Table structure:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="export">
   <colgroup>
    <col width="40" />
    <col width="*" />
    <col width="*" />
    <col width="*" />
    <col width="*" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr style="cursor:default;">
        <th align="center" style="text-align:center;">No</th>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:left;">Nama Usahawan</th>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:left;">Nama Peniagaan</th>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:left;">SSM No</th>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:left;">Kluster Perniagaan</th>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:left;">Created Date</th>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:left;">District</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TBodyList">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="left" style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When clicked on this link export script will be executed:***

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" onClick ="$('#export').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">[EXPORT TO PDF]</a> - refer to detail report!
```

***And this is how it shows up***
[image]

These are the scripts included to export table:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $BaseUrl; ?>js/tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $BaseUrl; ?>js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $BaseUrl; ?>js/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $BaseUrl; ?>js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $BaseUrl; ?>js/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script>
```

In the `tableExport.js` file, I altered the values for the below script to adjust the space, font size:

> Does anybody know how to adjust script below, to make the table appear
>   neatly on the pdf, please?

```
  $.fn.extend({
        tableExport: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
        separator: ',',
        ignoreColumn: [],
        tableName:'export',
        type:'pdf',
        pdfFontSize:8,
        pdfLeftMargin:5,
        escape:'true',
        htmlContent:'false',
        consoleLog:'false'
    };
 });
```

This is how the table ought to appear:

[image]

Comment: get rid of the colgroup and see if it looks better

Comment: @dandavis, removing the colgroup doesn't make any changes